# How can I fit a return statement in a ternary conditional?

Tags: c

I know ternary conditionals require expressions to work, but I was wondering if there is a clever workaround for something like this:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool in_asc_order(const int *arr, size_t arr_size)
{
    int count = 0;
    bool result = false;

    while(count < arr_size - 1)
    {
        (arr[count] <= arr[count + 1])? result = true : (return false);
        count++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Instead of writing something like this:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool in_asc_order(const int *arr, size_t arr_size)
{
    int count = 0;
    bool result = false;

    while(count < arr_size - 1)
    {
        if(arr[count] <= arr[count + 1])
        {
            result = true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        count++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I am keen on using this conditional. Any help would be great.

Comment: Learn about expressions. C is *mostly* about expressions. (some of ...) The syntax says: `STMT := return`EXPR ';' and EXPR can be a ternary expression.

Comment: Why not simplify your logic and only return early if the next element is greater than or equal to the previous?

Comment: You can't. Use an `if`.

Comment: @squiguy do you mean less than? This function is meant to return true if the int array is in ascending order.

Comment: Sorry, yes. I had it flipped.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't write either of those things.  How about this?

```
bool in_asc_order(const int *arr, size_t arr_size)
{
  if (arr_size == 0)
    return true;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < arr_size - 1; i++)
    if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
      return false;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it.  Probably should make `i` a `size_t`, though.  And check if `arr_size > 0` before doing anything.  Else signed/unsigned comparison madness may ensue.

Comment: Because I feel uncomfortable writing the default return as 'true'. Checking for false is not always the same as checking for 'true'. And it's not really the question I raised.

Comment: @Death_by_Ch0colate :the fast return is more compact than your *indicator variable*. It is also correct. (and a good candidate for inlining)

Comment: BTW: there seems to be a (tail)recursive version lurking in here, which could also be inlined.

Comment: Question closed, so here she goes: `bool in_asc_order(const int *arr, size_t arr_size)
{
  if (arr_size < 2) return true;
  if (arr[i] < arr[i + 1]) return false;
  return in_asc_order(arr+1, arr_size -1);
}`

Comment: Question not closed, I did not ask for a faster algorithm. I did not ask for a different(shorter) algorithm. I asked how to make the ternary conditional work.

Comment: With some effort you could turn my recursive version into a ternary. Still needs a `return *expression*;` ,though.

Comment: There you go: `bool in_asc_order(const int *arr, size_t arr_size)
{
  return (arr_size < 2) ? true
  : arr[0] > arr[1] ? false
  : in_asc_order(arr+1, arr_size -1);
}`  ... and, if you look correctly: it is only a single *expression* !